# IPC message queues how to send a vector of pairs

Tags: c++, unix, vector, ipc, message-queue

I'm trying to send and receive a message between 2 processes
the struct as follows

```
struct _st{
    long _var1;
    int _var2; 
    int _var3; 
    int _var4;
    int _var5;
    vector <pair<int,int> > _var6; 
};
```

and my sending code is

```
send_val = msgsnd(msgqid, &message, sizeof(message), !IPC_NOWAIT);
```

and i receive it this way

```
rec_val = msgrcv(msgqid, &message, sizeof(message), 0, !IPC_NOWAIT);
```

when i assign my _var6 from the received message to another variable and print it's values 
i get garbage.

How can i send and receive this struct correctly?

Comment: what type is your message variable?

Answer (score 3):

`_st` is not POD you cant' simply send over IPC without serialize/deserialize it. You are actually sending _var6 internal pointer over IPC not its content.

`sizeof(message)` will only get static `_st` struct size, it doesn't include contents size of `_var6`.
You need to serialize `_st` manually before msgsnd and deserialize it after msgrcv.

have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html