# Storing dynamic length data 'inside' structure

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

**Problem statement :** User provides some data which I have to store inside a structure. This data which I receive come in a data structure which allows user to dynamically add data to it.

**Requirement:**  I need a way to store this data *'inside'* the structure, *contiguously*.

eg. Suppose user can pass me strings which I have to store. So I wrote something like this :

```
void pushData( string userData )
{
    struct 
    {
       string junk;
    } data;

    data.junk = userData;
}
```

**Problem :** When I do this kind of storage, actual data is not really stored 'inside' the structure because string is not POD. Similar problem comes when I receive vector or list.

Then I could do something like this :

```
void pushData( string userData )
{
    struct 
    {
       char junk[100];
    } data;    

    // Copy userdata into array junk
}
```

This store the data 'inside' the structure, but then, I can't put an upper limit on the size of string user can provide.

Can someone suggest some approach ?

P.S. : I read something about serializability, but couldnt really make out clearly if it could be helpful in my case. If it is the way to go forward, can someone give idea how to proceed with it ?

---

Edit :

1. No this is not homework.
2. I have written an implementation which can pass this kind of structure over message queues. It works fine with PODs, but I need to extend it to pass on dynamic data as well.

This is how message queue takes data:

i. Give it a pointer and tell the size till which it should read and transfer data.

ii. For plain old data types, data is store inside the structure, I can easily pass on the pointer of this structure to message queue to other processes.

iii. But in case of vector/string/list etc, actual data is not inside the structure and thus if I pass on the pointer of this structure, message queue will not really pass on the actual data, but rather the pointers which would be stored inside this structure.

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181816/how-to-receive-dynamic-length-data-from-a-message-queue) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963653/ipc-message-queues-how-to-send-a-vector-of-pairs). I am trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So just to be clear: you'd like some structure `S` which to store an unbounded amount of data within its bod? The key thing is: can you know how large the data is before you allocate S?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void pushData( string userData )
{
    struct Data
    {
       char junk[1];
    };

    struct Data* data = malloc(userData.size() + 1);
    memcpy(data->junk, userData.data(), userData.size());
    data->junk[userData.size()] = '\0'; // assuming you want null termination
}
```

Here we use an array of length 1, but we allocate the struct using malloc so it can actually have any size we want.

Comment: As you are doing malloc i.e. allocating memory from the heap, how would you release the memory when the job is over?

Comment: While this might work in practice, it is of course undefined behavior to access anything but the first character in the array. Any implementation  can decide to trap the out-of-bounds access on the last line of code.

Comment: @BoPersson: I guess it's possible that this is not valid according to the standard, but the practice I have outlined is so widespread that no mainstream implementation could ever not support it.  Some people even use `[0]` for the array, and some use `[]`; at least I did something more portable than those!  I'm no big fan of sketchy code, but this isn't that.

Comment: @Subhajit: with `free()` of course!  I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You ostensibly have some rather artificial constraints, but to answer the question: for a single `struct` to contain a variable amount of data is not possible... the closest you can come is to have the final member be say `char [1]`, put such a struct at the start of a variably-sized heap region, and use the fact that array indexing is not checked to access memory beyond that character.  To learn about this technique, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html (or the answer John Zwinck just posted)

Another approach is e.g. `template <size_t N> struct X { char data_[size]; };`, but each instantiation will be a separate struct type, and you can't pre-instantiate every size you might want at run-time (given you've said you don't want an upper bound).  Even if you could, writing code that handles different instantiations as the data grows would be nightmarish, as would the code bloat caused.

Having a structure in one place with a string member with data in another place is almost always preferable to the hackery above.

Taking a hopefully-not-so-wild guess, I assume your interest is in serialising the object based on starting address and size, in some generic binary block read/write...?  If so, that's still problematic even if your goal were satisfied, as you need to find out the current data size from somewhere.  Writing struct-specific serialisation routines that incorporates the variable-length data on the heap is much more promising.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:estimate max_size of data (ex 1000), to prevent memory leak(if free memory & malloc new size memory -> fragment memory) when pushData multiple called.

```
#define MAX_SIZE 1000
void pushData( string userData )
{
 struct Data
 {
   char junk[MAX_SIZE];
 };


memcpy(data->junk, userData.data(), userData.size());
data->junk[userData.size()] = '\0'; // assuming you want null termination
}
```

Comment: Then we need to limit to MAX_SIZE only.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by John Zwinck....you can use dynamic memory allocation to solve your problem.

```
void pushData( string userData )
{
    struct Data
    {
       char *junk;
    };

    struct Data *d = calloc(sizeof(struct data), 1);
    d->junk = malloc(strlen(userData)+1);
    strcpy(d->junk, userdata);
}
```